# Oracle sequence primary key violated with Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: database, oracle, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a table in Oracle which has some values with different primary keys, for example values 1, 2, 27, 125...

In my entity in Symfony the annotation is:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="MY_KEY", type="decimal")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="TABLE_MY_KEY_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
```

And the Sequence generated in Oracle is:

[image: Oracle sequence]

When I insert a new register in that table, doctrine tries to insert in the first position (id = 1) so I have a error (PK violated, primary key duplicated), then tries with the second position (same error...) until finds I empty position. N times after we have the same error because tries to insert Primary Key with value 27 o 125 which is already in database. ¿How can I control this? Because from the first time, I need to have these values in the database and I don't know what values will be.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should alter the sequence. Suppose your max id in the table is 1500, then run

`ALTER SEQUENCE  TABLE_MY_KEY_seq
   MAXVALUE 1500;`

Your first id will be 1501.
Otherwise you should implement your own custom strategy as described here 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies